# unicode-math changing it and bfup font ranges

Tags: unicode-math

If I try to set up an independent font specifically for `\mathit` and/or `\mathbf` using

```
\setmathfont[range = it]{some italic font}
\setmathfont[range = bf]{some bold font}
```

unicode-math will not change it and just leave the default latex font. Other ranges do work, i.e. `bfit` and `up`. Haven't tested others...

`it` has a special issue. It falls back to vanilla latex italic font, Computer Modern or however it is called. If a different font was set using `fontspec` then it will fall back to its italic variant.

Code:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\usepackage{calc, geometry}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{unicode-math}

\setmathfont[StylisticSet = 008]{STIX Two Math}
\setmathfont[range = bfup]{some upright bold font}
\setmathfont[range = it]{some italic font}

\begin{document}

\[ \mathbfit{F=ma} \quad \mathbf{F=ma} \quad F=ma \quad \mathit{F=ma}\]

\end{document}
```

Comment: Please do not use `$$` for display maths in LaTeX. LaTeX-2e made it obsolete decades ago.

Comment: Please make your code compilable. Unless somebody has fonts with those names, it won't work. Since these issues often involve specifics of particular fonts, give us some particular fonts it doesn't work as you expect with.

Comment: How is this different from https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/411785/unicode-math-use-different-font-for-latin-alphabet? You have not taken any notice of Will Robertson's request that you please give examples with real fonts from CTAN and not substitute non-working stuff like `some italic font`.  There, your example appears to include settings for the ranges you give here (and some more), and you've said that Will's answer solved the problem there. So what's the new question exactly?

Comment: Read the post again. This time unbiased. I put that font name because it does the same with any font I try. If I were to put the font I use, you will probably say something like "I don't have the exact same font you used, but here it is working (not really) with this other font" which helps me a lot but not enough.

Comment: Please also note the difference between `\mathit`/`\mathbf` and `\symit`/`\symbf`, etc.! Using `range` will only affect the `\sym..` commands.

Comment: @Suppboi No, there are fonts in CTAN which are part of every TeX distribution, such as `texgyrepagella-regular.otf`, `texgyrepagella-math.otf` and so on and so on.

Comment: I had in mind what @WillRobertson said above and in comments on your other question about this. Unless it is font-specific and can't be reproduced with the standardly-available fonts we all have (in which case, we need to know the fonts), pick fonts from that set to demonstrate the issue. That's the point of giving example code: other people can compile it to reproduce your situation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it by just changing the order of the font assignments. Putting `unicode-math's` `\setmathfont`commands before `fontspec's` `\setmainfont` command as shown

```
\newcommand{\garamondPremierPro}{
    ItalicFont = Garamond Premier Pro Italic Caption,
    BoldFont = Garamond Premier Pro Bold Caption,
    BoldItalicFont = Garamond Premier Pro Bold Italic Caption,  
}

\newcommand{\normalFontFeatures}{
    Kerning = On,
    Style = Historic,
    Ligatures = {Historic, Rare},
    % VerticalPosition = Denominator,
}

\setmathfont[StylisticSet = 008]{STIX Two Math}
\setmathfont[range = up/{Latin, latin}]{Garamond Premier Pro Caption}
\setmathfont[range = bfit/{Latin,latin}]{Garamond Premier Pro Bold Italic Caption}

\setmainfont[
    Language = English,
    \garamondPremierPro
    \normalFontFeatures
]{Garamond Premier Pro Caption}
```

P.S. There's the font I was using :)

Comment: ER, that doesn't look like a math mode font to me!

Comment: it's ok, it works!